# In how many ways can 3 exams can be conducted within a week, so that 2 examination are not scheduled on same day

Tags: permutations, combinations

I think I m bit confused between permutation and combination please clarify that

Comment: Say you have a calculus exam on Monday and a stats exam on Tuesday.  Is that the same arrangement as the stats on Monday and calculus on Tuesday?  This line of thinking should tell you whether to use permutations or combinations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have $3$ exams within $7$ days with each exam having a different day

This is equivalent to choosing $3$ objects from $7$ objects.

This can be done in $\binom{7}{3}$

But if the order of the exams is important, then this can be done in

$\binom{7}{3}\cdot 3!$